# CAAnimationGroup reverts to original position on completion

Tags: ios, animation

In iOS I'm trying to create the effect of an icon shrinking in size, and flying across the screen in an arc while fading out, and then disappearing. I've achieved these 3 effects with an CAAnimationGroup, and it does what I want. The problem is when the animation ends, the view appears back at the original position, full size and full opacity.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong in the code below?
The animation should not revert to it's original position, but just disappear at the end.

```
UIBezierPath *movePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
CGPoint libraryIconCenter = CGPointMake(610, 40);

CGPoint ctlPoint = CGPointMake(self.imgViewCropped.center.x, 22.0);
movePath moveToPoint:self.imgViewCropped.center];
[movePath addQuadCurveToPoint:libraryIconCenter
              controlPoint:ctlPoint];

 CAKeyframeAnimation *moveAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
 moveAnim.path = movePath.CGPath;
 moveAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

 CABasicAnimation *scaleAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
 scaleAnim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
 scaleAnim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 1.0)];
 scaleAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

 CABasicAnimation *opacityAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"alpha"];
 opacityAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
 opacityAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
 opacityAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

 CAAnimationGroup *animGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
 animGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:moveAnim,scaleAnim,opacityAnim, nil];
 animGroup.duration = 0.6;
 animGroup.delegate = self;
 animGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;
 [self.imgViewCropped.layer addAnimation:animGroup forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe you need to set the `fillMode` property of your animations to `kCAFillModeForwards`. That should freeze the animations at their end time. Another suggestion (and honestly, this is what I'd usually do) is just se the properties of the layer itself to their final position after you've set up the animation. That way when the animation is removed, the layer will still have the final properties as part of its model.

As an aside, the `removedOnCompletion` flag of animations contained within a `CAAnimationGroup` is ignored. You should probably just remove those assignments since they're misleading. Replace them with assignments to `fillMode` as specified above.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Kevin - I've set the fillMode as suggested, but the UIImageView still re-appears back at it's original position when the animation ends. I've added `self.imgViewCropped.layer.frame = CGRectMake(610,-40, 40, 40);`  after the animation block, but it takes effect immediately, before the animation runs.

Comment: Actually my code is based on this tutorial... [link]http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-3  but this suffers from the same problem in that the image re-appears baxck at the original position when the animation ends.

Comment: @Paul: Did you try just setting `self.imgViewCropped.layer.position` instead? And it definitely shouldn't just jump straight there. Your animation specifies the full path, so it's not pulling it out of the current value, and the animation's value for position will override whatever the layer is trying to use.

Comment: yes that works to some degree, in that it now "ends up" at the correct position on the screen. But it still shows full size, full opacity for a split second. I guess I need to set the frame size too, but if I do that it takes effect immediately. Do you just set layer.position or do you also set frame  height width somewhere?

Comment: You're not modifying the frame in your animation. You should set the position, transform, and alpha values to their final values.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. I was not setting the transform. Once that's done it's all working as expected. Thanks.